# How to change the port for Supabase self-hosted Docker service when port 4000 is already allocated?

Tags: docker, supabase

I'm attempting to run a self-hosted instance of Supabase using Docker on my VPS, and I've run into an issue where the service's analytics component is failing to start. The error message I'm encountering is as follows:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint supabase-analytics (ace49eaa77fbbf0f7e368877772b9d73ad61e41ef196f89347fbb31e683c3b7d): Bind for 0.0.0.0:4000 failed: port is already allocated
```

It appears that port 4000 is already in use on my VPS. How can I change the port for the Supabase analytics service in my Docker configuration to resolve this port conflict?

here is my `docker-compose.yaml` file :

```yaml
# Usage
#   Start:          docker compose up
#   With helpers:   docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f ./dev/docker-compose.dev.yml up
#   Stop:           docker compose down
#   Destroy:        docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f ./dev/docker-compose.dev.yml down -v --remove-orphans

version: "3.8"

services:

  studio:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-studio
    image: supabase/studio:20230921-d657f29
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "node",
          "-e",
          "require('http').get('http://localhost:3000/api/profile', (r) => {if (r.statusCode !== 200) throw new Error(r.statusCode)})"
        ]
      timeout: 5s
      interval: 5s
      retries: 3
    depends_on:
      analytics:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      STUDIO_PG_META_URL: http://meta:8080
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

      DEFAULT_ORGANIZATION_NAME: ${STUDIO_DEFAULT_ORGANIZATION}
      DEFAULT_PROJECT_NAME: ${STUDIO_DEFAULT_PROJECT}

      SUPABASE_URL: http://kong:8000
      SUPABASE_PUBLIC_URL: ${SUPABASE_PUBLIC_URL}
      SUPABASE_ANON_KEY: ${ANON_KEY}
      SUPABASE_SERVICE_KEY: ${SERVICE_ROLE_KEY}

      LOGFLARE_API_KEY: ${LOGFLARE_API_KEY}
      LOGFLARE_URL: http://analytics:4000
      NEXT_PUBLIC_ENABLE_LOGS: true
      # Comment to use Big Query backend for analytics
      NEXT_ANALYTICS_BACKEND_PROVIDER: postgres
      # Uncomment to use Big Query backend for analytics
      # NEXT_ANALYTICS_BACKEND_PROVIDER: bigquery

  kong:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-kong
    image: kong:2.8.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    # https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294837
    entrypoint: bash -c 'eval "echo \"$$(cat ~/temp.yml)\"" > ~/kong.yml && /docker-entrypoint.sh kong docker-start'
    ports:
      - ${KONG_HTTP_PORT}:8000/tcp
      - ${KONG_HTTPS_PORT}:8443/tcp
    depends_on:
      analytics:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: "off"
      KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG: /home/kong/kong.yml
      # https://github.com/supabase/cli/issues/14
      KONG_DNS_ORDER: LAST,A,CNAME
      KONG_PLUGINS: request-transformer,cors,key-auth,acl,basic-auth
      KONG_NGINX_PROXY_PROXY_BUFFER_SIZE: 160k
      KONG_NGINX_PROXY_PROXY_BUFFERS: 64 160k
      SUPABASE_ANON_KEY: ${ANON_KEY}
      SUPABASE_SERVICE_KEY: ${SERVICE_ROLE_KEY}
      DASHBOARD_USERNAME: ${DASHBOARD_USERNAME}
      DASHBOARD_PASSWORD: ${DASHBOARD_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      # https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/12661
      - ./volumes/api/kong.yml:/home/kong/temp.yml:ro

  auth:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-auth
    image: supabase/gotrue:v2.99.0
    depends_on:
      db:
        # Disable this if you are using an external Postgres database
        condition: service_healthy
      analytics:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "wget",
          "--no-verbose",
          "--tries=1",
          "--spider",
          "http://localhost:9999/health"
        ]
      timeout: 5s
      interval: 5s
      retries: 3
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      GOTRUE_API_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      GOTRUE_API_PORT: 9999
      API_EXTERNAL_URL: ${API_EXTERNAL_URL}

      GOTRUE_DB_DRIVER: postgres
      GOTRUE_DB_DATABASE_URL: postgres://supabase_auth_admin:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}

      GOTRUE_SITE_URL: ${SITE_URL}
      GOTRUE_URI_ALLOW_LIST: ${ADDITIONAL_REDIRECT_URLS}
      GOTRUE_DISABLE_SIGNUP: ${DISABLE_SIGNUP}

      GOTRUE_JWT_ADMIN_ROLES: service_role
      GOTRUE_JWT_AUD: authenticated
      GOTRUE_JWT_DEFAULT_GROUP_NAME: authenticated
      GOTRUE_JWT_EXP: ${JWT_EXPIRY}
      GOTRUE_JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}

      GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_EMAIL_ENABLED: ${ENABLE_EMAIL_SIGNUP}
      GOTRUE_MAILER_AUTOCONFIRM: ${ENABLE_EMAIL_AUTOCONFIRM}
      # GOTRUE_MAILER_SECURE_EMAIL_CHANGE_ENABLED: true
      # GOTRUE_SMTP_MAX_FREQUENCY: 1s
      GOTRUE_SMTP_ADMIN_EMAIL: ${SMTP_ADMIN_EMAIL}
      GOTRUE_SMTP_HOST: ${SMTP_HOST}
      GOTRUE_SMTP_PORT: ${SMTP_PORT}
      GOTRUE_SMTP_USER: ${SMTP_USER}
      GOTRUE_SMTP_PASS: ${SMTP_PASS}
      GOTRUE_SMTP_SENDER_NAME: ${SMTP_SENDER_NAME}
      GOTRUE_MAILER_URLPATHS_INVITE: ${MAILER_URLPATHS_INVITE}
      GOTRUE_MAILER_URLPATHS_CONFIRMATION: ${MAILER_URLPATHS_CONFIRMATION}
      GOTRUE_MAILER_URLPATHS_RECOVERY: ${MAILER_URLPATHS_RECOVERY}
      GOTRUE_MAILER_URLPATHS_EMAIL_CHANGE: ${MAILER_URLPATHS_EMAIL_CHANGE}

      GOTRUE_EXTERNAL_PHONE_ENABLED: ${ENABLE_PHONE_SIGNUP}
      GOTRUE_SMS_AUTOCONFIRM: ${ENABLE_PHONE_AUTOCONFIRM}

  rest:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-rest
    image: postgrest/postgrest:v11.2.0
    depends_on:
      db:
        # Disable this if you are using an external Postgres database
        condition: service_healthy
      analytics:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PGRST_DB_URI: postgres://authenticator:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}
      PGRST_DB_SCHEMAS: ${PGRST_DB_SCHEMAS}
      PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE: anon
      PGRST_JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      PGRST_DB_USE_LEGACY_GUCS: "false"
      PGRST_APP_SETTINGS_JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      PGRST_APP_SETTINGS_JWT_EXP: ${JWT_EXPIRY}
    command: "postgrest"

  realtime:
    container_name: runwin-realtime-dev.supabase-realtime
    image: supabase/realtime:v2.10.1
    depends_on:
      db:
        # Disable this if you are using an external Postgres database
        condition: service_healthy
      analytics:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "bash",
          "-c",
          "printf \\0 > /dev/tcp/localhost/4000"
        ]
      timeout: 5s
      interval: 5s
      retries: 3
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PORT: 4000
      DB_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
      DB_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
      DB_USER: supabase_admin
      DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      DB_NAME: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      DB_AFTER_CONNECT_QUERY: 'SET search_path TO _realtime'
      DB_ENC_KEY: supabaserealtime
      API_JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      FLY_ALLOC_ID: fly123
      FLY_APP_NAME: realtime
      SECRET_KEY_BASE: UpNVntn3cDxHJpq99YMc1T1AQgQpc8kfYTuRgBiYa15BLrx8etQoXz3gZv1/u2oq
      ERL_AFLAGS: -proto_dist inet_tcp
      ENABLE_TAILSCALE: "false"
      DNS_NODES: "''"
    command: >
      sh -c "/app/bin/migrate && /app/bin/realtime eval 'Realtime.Release.seeds(Realtime.Repo)' && /app/bin/server"

  storage:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-storage
    image: supabase/storage-api:v0.40.4
    depends_on:
      db:
        # Disable this if you are using an external Postgres database
        condition: service_healthy
      rest:
        condition: service_started
      imgproxy:
        condition: service_started
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "wget",
          "--no-verbose",
          "--tries=1",
          "--spider",
          "http://localhost:5000/status"
        ]
      timeout: 5s
      interval: 5s
      retries: 3
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      ANON_KEY: ${ANON_KEY}
      SERVICE_KEY: ${SERVICE_ROLE_KEY}
      POSTGREST_URL: http://rest:3000
      PGRST_JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://supabase_storage_admin:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}
      FILE_SIZE_LIMIT: 52428800
      STORAGE_BACKEND: file
      FILE_STORAGE_BACKEND_PATH: /var/lib/storage
      TENANT_ID: stub
      # TODO: https://github.com/supabase/storage-api/issues/55
      REGION: stub
      GLOBAL_S3_BUCKET: stub
      ENABLE_IMAGE_TRANSFORMATION: "true"
      IMGPROXY_URL: http://imgproxy:5001
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/storage:/var/lib/storage:z

  imgproxy:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-imgproxy
    image: darthsim/imgproxy:v3.8.0
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "imgproxy", "health" ]
      timeout: 5s
      interval: 5s
      retries: 3
    environment:
      IMGPROXY_BIND: ":5001"
      IMGPROXY_LOCAL_FILESYSTEM_ROOT: /
      IMGPROXY_USE_ETAG: "true"
      IMGPROXY_ENABLE_WEBP_DETECTION: ${IMGPROXY_ENABLE_WEBP_DETECTION}
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/storage:/var/lib/storage:z

  meta:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-meta
    image: supabase/postgres-meta:v0.68.0
    depends_on:
      db:
        # Disable this if you are using an external Postgres database
        condition: service_healthy
      analytics:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PG_META_PORT: 8080
      PG_META_DB_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
      PG_META_DB_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
      PG_META_DB_NAME: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      PG_META_DB_USER: supabase_admin
      PG_META_DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

  functions:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-edge-functions
    image: supabase/edge-runtime:v1.20.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      analytics:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      SUPABASE_URL: http://kong:8000
      SUPABASE_ANON_KEY: ${ANON_KEY}
      SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY: ${SERVICE_ROLE_KEY}
      SUPABASE_DB_URL: postgresql://postgres:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}
      # TODO: Allow configuring VERIFY_JWT per function. This PR might help: https://github.com/supabase/cli/pull/786
      VERIFY_JWT: "${FUNCTIONS_VERIFY_JWT}"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/functions:/home/deno/functions:Z
    command:
      - start
      - --main-service
      - /home/deno/functions/main

  analytics:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-analytics
    image: supabase/logflare:1.4.0
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "http://localhost:4000/health" ]
      timeout: 5s
      interval: 5s
      retries: 10
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      db:
        # Disable this if you are using an external Postgres database
        condition: service_healthy
    # Uncomment to use Big Query backend for analytics
    # volumes:
    #   - type: bind
    #     source: ${PWD}/gcloud.json
    #     target: /opt/app/rel/logflare/bin/gcloud.json
    #     read_only: true
    environment:
      LOGFLARE_NODE_HOST:  127.0.0.1
      DB_USERNAME: supabase_admin
      DB_DATABASE: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      DB_HOSTNAME: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
      DB_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      DB_SCHEMA: _analytics
      LOGFLARE_API_KEY: ${LOGFLARE_API_KEY}
      LOGFLARE_SINGLE_TENANT: true
      LOGFLARE_SUPABASE_MODE: true
      LOGFLARE_MIN_CLUSTER_SIZE: 1
      RELEASE_COOKIE: cookie

      # Comment variables to use Big Query backend for analytics
      POSTGRES_BACKEND_URL: postgresql://supabase_admin:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_BACKEND_SCHEMA: _analytics
      LOGFLARE_FEATURE_FLAG_OVERRIDE: multibackend=true

      # Uncomment to use Big Query backend for analytics
      # GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: ${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}
      # GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER: ${GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER}
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    entrypoint: |
                  sh -c `cat <<'EOF' > run.sh && sh run.sh
                  ./logflare eval Logflare.Release.migrate
                  ./logflare start --sname logflare
                  EOF
                  `

  # Comment out everything below this point if you are using an external Postgres database
  db:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-db
    image: supabase/postgres:15.1.0.117
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres -h localhost
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    depends_on:
      vector:
        condition: service_healthy
    command:
      - postgres
      - -c
      - config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
      - -c
      - log_min_messages=fatal # prevents Realtime polling queries from appearing in logs
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      # Pass down internal port because it's set dynamically by other services
      - 127.0.0.1:${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: /var/run/postgresql
      PGPORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
      POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
      PGPASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      PGDATABASE: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/db/realtime.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migrations/99-realtime.sql:Z
      # Must be superuser to create event trigger
      - ./volumes/db/webhooks.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-scripts/98-webhooks.sql:Z
      # Must be superuser to alter reserved role
      - ./volumes/db/roles.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-scripts/99-roles.sql:Z
      # PGDATA directory is persisted between restarts
      - ./volumes/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      # Changes required for Analytics support
      - ./volumes/db/logs.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migrations/99-logs.sql:Z

  vector:
    container_name: runwin-supabase-vector
    image: timberio/vector:0.28.1-alpine
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [

          "CMD",
          "wget",
          "--no-verbose",
          "--tries=1",
          "--spider",
          "http://vector:9001/health"
        ]
      timeout: 5s
      interval: 5s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/logs/vector.yml:/etc/vector/vector.yml:ro
      - ${DOCKER_SOCKET_LOCATION}:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

    command: [ "--config", "etc/vector/vector.yml" ]
```

Any guidance or steps to reconfigure the port for Supabase analytics within the Docker setup would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your docker configuration to the question?

Comment: @maxm edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing, try and update the `docker-compose.yaml` file to specify a [different port](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) for the [Supabase analytics service](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/self-hosting/docker).
Your `docker-compose.yaml` file would include:

```yaml
services:

  studio:
    ...
    environment:
      ...
      LOGFLARE_URL: http://analytics:4001
      ...

  ...

  analytics:
    ...
    ports:
      - 4001:4000
    ...
```

The Supabase Analytics service would then be available on port `4001` of your VPS, which should help with the port conflict issue.

```bash
+-------------------+       +------------------------+       +---------------------+
| VPS               |       | Docker Service         |       | Supabase Analytics  |
|                   | ----> | docker-compose.yaml    | ----> | Port 4001 (changed) |
+-------------------+       +------------------------+       +---------------------+
```

---

> Is this the only place you'd need to set the new port?
> I'm running multiple self-hosted supabase instances on one VPS.

When running multiple self-hosted Supabase instances on a single VPS and changing the port for the Supabase Analytics service, you need to make sure each Supabase instance uses unique ports for all its services to avoid conflicts. That includes not just the Analytics service but also other services like Kong, PostgREST, Realtime, etc.

```bash
+-----------------------------------+
| VPS (Multiple Supabase Instances) |
+-----------------------------------+
| +------------+    +------------+  |
| | Instance 1 |    | Instance 2 |  |
| |            |    |            |  |
| | Analytics  |    | Analytics  |  |
| | Port 4001  |    | Port 4002  |  |
| |            |    |            |  |
| | Other      |    | Other      |  |
| | Services   |    | Services   |  |
| | Different  |    | Different  |  |
| | Ports      |    | Ports      |  |
| +------------+    +------------+  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

That means if services like Studio or any other components depend on the Analytics service, their environment variables (`LOGFLARE_URL`, etc.) should point to the correct, updated port number.
And if you are using Docker's internal networking (like custom bridges), make sure the services within the same Supabase instance can communicate with each other using their designated ports.

Also, for any service that needs to be accessible outside the Docker network (like for web interfaces or APIs), make sure the port mappings in the `docker-compose.yaml` file are correctly set up for external access.
Update your VPS's firewall or security group settings to allow traffic on the new ports as needed.

This is what you need to consider when you will review and update the `docker-compose.yaml` files for each Supabase instance to reflect the unique port configurations(!).

Comment: Is this the only place you'd need to set the new port? I'm running multiple self hosted supabase instances on one VPS.

Comment: @riccardolardi I have edited the answer to address your question.